# What is the short way for if-statement in inotify instance?

Tags: c

In this code, I just included **5 pathnames**. Although the pathnames can increase also. This code is working fine and notifying the filesystem correctly. But my question is that if there are **100s** or **1000s** of files, then will I have to write `if-statement if(event-wd == wd[0])` or `switch-statement` for each pathname. Is there any short way?

```
char pathname[5][100] = {"/home/runner/TestC1", "path/to/folder2", "path/to/folder3", "path/to/folder4", "path/to/folder5"};

int main(){
  int length, i = 0, fd, wd[5];
  char buffer[EVENT_BUF_LEN];

  fd = inotify_init();
  if (fd < 0){
      perror( "inotify_init" );
  }
  for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    wd[i] = inotify_add_watch( fd, pathname[i], IN_CREATE);
  }
  length = read( fd, buffer, EVENT_BUF_LEN ); 
  if(length < 0){
      perror("read");
  }  

  while(i < length){     
    struct inotify_event *event = ( struct inotify_event *)&buffer[i];
      if(event->len){
          if(event->mask & IN_CREATE){
              if(event->mask & IN_ISDIR){
                if(event->wd == wd[0]){
                  printf( "New directory %s created in %s\n", event->name, pathname[0]);
                }
                else if(event->wd == wd[1]){
                  printf( "New directory %s created in %s\n", event->name, pathname[1]);
                }
                else if(event->wd == wd[2]){
                  printf( "New directory %s created in %s\n", event->name, pathname[2]);
                }
                else if(event->wd == wd[3]){
                  printf( "New directory %s created in %s\n", event->name, pathname[3]);
                }
                else if(event->wd == wd[4]){
                  printf( "New directory %s created in %s\n", event->name, pathname[4]);
                }
              }
          }
      }
      i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
  }
  for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    inotify_rm_watch(fd, wd[i]);
  }
  close(fd);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `for` loops.

Instead of this:

```
if(event->wd == wd[0]){
  printf( "New directory %s created in %s\n", event->name, pathname[0]);
}
else if(event->wd == wd[1]){
  printf( "New directory %s created in %s\n", event->name, pathname[1]);
}
else if(event->wd == wd[2]){
  printf( "New directory %s created in %s\n", event->name, pathname[2]);
}
else if(event->wd == wd[3]){
  printf( "New directory %s created in %s\n", event->name, pathname[3]);
}
else if(event->wd == wd[4]){
  printf( "New directory %s created in %s\n", event->name, pathname[4]);
}
```

You can use this:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
  if(event->wd == wd[j]){
    printf( "New directory %s created in %s\n", event->name, pathname[j]);
    break;
  }
}
```